# How do I list currently running shell scripts?

Tags: scripting, shell

I think I have a shell script (launched by root's crontab) that's stuck in a loop. How do I list running scripts and how can I kill them?

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04, but I imagine it's similar for all *nix systems...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ps -ef` will show you list of the currently running processes. Last field is the process name and parameters. Find the process you are looking for, and look at the 2nd column. 2nd column is process id or `pid`.

Then do `kill -9 <pid>` to kill that particular process.

Comment: So what's the 9 for? It seems to work without it....

Comment: @Nick: Normally kill sends a `SIGTERM` to the process, allowing it to shut down appropriately. Adding `-9` sends a `SIGKILL` instead, causing it to shut down forcibly without any chance of cleanup. See the `signal(7)` man page for some more details.

Comment: It's an equivalent of "force". Meaning nothing could block the kill command.

Comment: Except being in the middle of kernel code. Not even `SIGKILL` can interrupt that.

Comment: That's what the power buttons for... ;)

Comment: Some references: [When should I use kill -9?](http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html), [kill -9](http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html), [Useless use of kill -9](http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/)

Answer (score 9):

If you want a more stripped down version with better ASCII art (in my opinion I suppose) you can do

```
pstree -p
```

Comment: Perfect for identifying an (interrupted) ssh session with a long running process

Answer (score 2):

`ps auxfwww` will give you an ASCII art tree diagram of all the processes running on the system. From there it's just a matter of tracing down from the cron daemon and running `kill` against the appropriate PID.

Answer (score 1):

Or just good old `top` command, which will show a toplist of most resource-hungry processes.